# Easiest way to copy all the stored procedure and function at once from one sql server to another

Tags: sql-server

i need to copy all the stored procedure and function at once from one sql server database to another.

is it possible than how?

Answer (score 25):

- In SQL Server Management Studio, go to the Object Explorer
- Find your database
- Right-click on it `> Tasks > Generate Scripts`

[image]

- Pick stored procedures and functions as your objects to script out

[image]

- Script them out to a file (or a bunch of files)
- Run those files on your other SQL Server

Or if your two SQL Servers are on the same network, you could also use a tool like [Red-Gate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) to just compare the structures and copy all stored proc and functions from your source server to your destination.

Comment: we need to copy the procedures, not to execute them

Comment: @AllfaridMoralesGarcía: **yes** - this generates a **SQL script** which you can then copy to the other server and execute there to **re-create** all those procedures .....