# Oracle SQL Developer how to copy multiple procedures from one server to another

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]What is the best way to copy procedures from one server to another I dont want to copy and paste each one and run which I am doing currently. I have a staging database and a target database. I have procedures that are in target that are not in staging how do I go about this? I've researched about merge but that only works for tables... I think?

Comment: This is the wrong approach. Write proper SQL scripts, store them in a version control system and deploy them from there. Tools like Liquibase or Flyway help you with organizing and running the scripts.

Answer (score 1):

'Best' - no way to answer without knowing more about what you want.

You can drag and drop a procedure or procedures from one database connection to another and we'll copy them over. V4.1.5 or v4.2.

In all other versions you can use Tools > Database > Copy and select your PL/SQL and target database and we'll copy them over.

Def don't copy and paste.

What you should probably really do is have a working directory of all your source code, and then you could load them up in whatever database you want by calling them @ style with a SQL*Plus script against the target database.

SQL Developer will run the SQL*Plus scripts for you via F5 in a SQL Worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dbms_metadata procedure to extract DDL statements for the stored procedure and function. Try something like this:

```
spool procedures_mydb.sql
select dbms_metadata.GET_DDL('PROCEDURE',u.object_name)
from user_objects u
where object_type = 'PROCEDURE'
;
spool off;
```

Then run created file on another instance.

Answer (score -1):

-select source database
-Right-click on source database>Tasks>Generate Script> 
-select Stored Procedures
-check the required stored procedures and save as a single file.

Once the file is saved, open the file and rename the database to required(target) database name.

Below link may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9238983/6929319

Comment: Hi, your link is for a SQL Server solution and not SQL Developer.

Comment: How is this relevant for Oracle?

Comment: The question **clearly** says **Oracle** in the title, mentions **Oracle SQL Developer**, and has tags for **Oracle**. How are instructions and a link for **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio** relevant here?